# Function: Print border around list

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, output-formatting

I'm trying to print a border of "#" around the list provided and so far managed to get the correct length. But there's a condition where it would print a '.' on the row on the right side where 'A' would appear first in the list as an 'opening.' How would I create a condition to print it properly?

I will be using this function for other lists with different lengths as well.

**Code I have:**

```
area0   =   [['.', 'A', 'A', '.', '.', '.'],['.', '.', '.', '.', '.',]]
def show_locale(area):
    count = len(area) + 4 
    mark = "#"*count 
    return "#{mark}#\n# {area} \n#{mark}#".format(mark=mark,area=area)
show_locale(area0)
```

**What I want to print:**

```
print(show_lot(lot0))
########
#.AA....
#......#
########
```

Example 2:

```
print(show_lot(lot3))
######
#...f#
#AA.e.
#...f#
#.XXX#
#....#
#.yZZ#
######
```

Comment: you can just check the length of each row and append with "." or "#" accordingly. or am I missing something? can you share more examples?

Comment: Added another print example.

Answer (score 1):

- first, the `count` is incorrect. You're counting the rows, where you should count the columns.
- second, you have to convert your lists to strings using `str.join`
- third, there's a condition on the ending that I coded in a ternary expression within a list comprehension: if the row contains `A` it "opens" the end, else it ends with `#`. Not sure if it covers all the cases...

EDIT: changed the condition by: if all dots, then end with `#` else leave "open".

That does what you want (the lengths of the rows are handled by a hack ATM with the non-complete example you provided)

```
area0   =   [['.', 'A', 'A', '.', '.', '.'],['.', '.', '.', '.', '.',]]
def show_locale(area):
    count = len(area[0]) + 2
    mark = "#"*count
    ##return "\n".join([mark]+["".join(['#']+a+['.' if 'A' in a else '.#']) for a in area0]+[mark])
    return "\n".join([mark]+["".join(['#']+a+['.#' if all(x=='.' for x in a) else '.']) for a in area0]+[mark])
print(show_locale(area0))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Add the condition for 'A' appearing at the first position in the list**

Here's another solution, that works for lists of different lengths.

```
area0   =   [['.', 'A', 'A', '.', '.', '.'],['.', '.', '.', '.', '.',], ['A', '.', '.', '.',]]

def print_box(l):
    max_len = 0
    for i in l:
        max_len = max(max_len, len(i))
    print("#" * (max_len+2))
    for i in l:
        if i[0] == 'A':
            # Print an open end
            print("#{}".format("".join(i).ljust(max_len, " ")))
        else:
            print("#{}#".format("".join(i).ljust(max_len, " ")))
    print("#" * (max_len+2))

print_box(area0)
```

**Output**

```
########
#.AA...#
#..... #
#A...  
########
```

Shorter lists will be padded with spaces.